# How do I mock a promise in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to write a test which mocks a promise in reactjs

I just need a mocked implementation of getHeaders() to return a string

```
export const loadAllProjects = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        getHeaders()
            .then(headers => {
                ...do stuff
            })
    }
}
```

to clarify my original function was...

```
export const loadAllProjects = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
                ...do stuff
    }
}
```

...and my test was...

```
    it('should create SET_ALL_PROJECTS action when fetching projects', () => {
    fetchMock
        .getOnce('http://test.projects.api/api/projects',
        {
            body: [{name: "x"}],
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        }).spy()
    const expectedActions = [
        { type: "SET_ALL_PROJECTS", json: [{name:"x"}] },
    ]
    checkAsyncActionsWereDispatched(expectedActions, actions.loadAllProjects)
});
```

I want the test to work with the mocked header

Comment: How are you mocking fetch? You have something called `fetchMock` is that from the library fetch-mock?

Comment: Yes, Henrik, it is from the fetch-mock library

Comment: While I don't think I can help much with your question I found that using fetch and fetchmock resulted in more headaches than necessary. The mocking needs to occur before requiring the `checkAsyncActionsWereDispatched` function, it can also be necessary to use `require` instead of `import` syntax. The problems were so many with fetch and fetch mock that I opted for axios and normal jest mocking instead. :(

Comment: does `getHeaders` comes from another module? If not it will be impossible to mock with jest at the moment.

Comment: getHeaders is in the same file as loadAllProjects(), Andreas. It also does a fetch which is why I want to mock it. I can put it in a different module...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Henrik

Answer (score 8):

```
const getHeaders = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("some string");
    });
};

a = await getHeaders();    //some string
```

Comment: Thanks - I have edited the question to show the original test

Answer (score 1):

Use `Promise.resolve`

```
return Promise.resolve("your headers here");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question to show the original test I have

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jest](https://jestjs.io) to mock a promise for testing

Example for the eventual completion:

```
const mockPostSpy = jest
.spyOn(axios, 'post')
.mockImplementation(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        return resolve({
            data: {},
        });
    });
});
```

Example for the operation failed:

```
const mockPostSpy = jest
.spyOn(axios, 'post')
.mockImplementation(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        return reject({});
    });
});
```

Good luck to you ^^